# Unable to access any router interface via ethernet cable using Windows 10 laptop

Tags: router

I am a newbie so please be kind.
My objective is to use a new Tenda dual band AC6 as a wired access point.  The default gateway is 192.168.0.1.
I connect my Windows 10 laptop USB port (no ethernet port) using a qts1081B adapter to a Lan port on the router whilst not connected to the internet then type http://192.168.0.1 into any browser I get "Not secure" in the browser window and no access to the router. This happens  with 3 different browsers.

I bought the Tenda despite already  having a spare Gigatex router because the same happened when trying to configure that as an AP, no access, so I  thought the router was at fault. It seems the laptop will not connect  to either router interface by ethernet cable.

Please help.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the "Not secure" screen. Use the [Edit] button.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to try https://192.168.0.1, maybe your router already hosts a secure configurations page as well. If it does not work:

HTTP is not secure to use over the internet. Since you only want use it to access a device on your own local network, you can do so. I might have to acknowledged your browser warning or set the browser to display HTTP sites as well (depending on the browser and the current settings).

If you change your router configuration page from http to https, the warning will not be displayed again.